# Relational database question with php

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Not really a coding question more a little help with my idea of a Relational database.

If I have 3 tables in a SQL database. In my php script I basically query the companies which are in industry "a" and then insert a row into a separate table with their details such as companyId , companyName etc is that a type of Relational database ?

I have explained it in a simple way so we don't get confused what I am trying to say.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track.

What you are describing is known as the concept of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), where separate (and unique) forms of data are divided into entities (in your case, an industry and a company) that are related in some way.

And, furthermore, the proper name for that relationship is "one-to-many," where one entity has many entities that belong to it (one industry has many companies).

Answer (score 1):

> is that a type of Relational database
>   ?

From what I understood ...
Table Industry has many Companies.
So this IS a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some SQL that you could use to create the tables to store the companies and industries

```
CREATE TABLE `industry`
(
`ind_id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ind_name` VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (`ind_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `company`
(
`com_id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
`com_name` VARCHAR(255),
`com_address` VARCHAR(255),
`com_city` VARCHAR(255),
`ind_id` INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (`com_id`)
);
```

Optionally you could create on index to enforce the relational integrity

```
CREATE INDEX `company_ind_id_idxfk` ON `company`(`ind_id`);
ALTER TABLE `company` ADD FOREIGN KEY ind_id_idxfk (`ind_id`) REFERENCES `industry` (`ind_id`);
```